# Cannot read property 'onDeleteClick' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On the first `<div>`, `onDeleteClick` is working, but on the second one, the `onDeleteClick` function is getting `undefined`. I am getting the `this` reference but click is not working, getting `undefined`.

I am not able to understand why the first `<div>` which has the function `onDeleteClick` is working fine but for the second one that is a collection for which I am getting the reference of `this`, but "*onDeleteClick of undefined*" is thrown on click of that.

```
onDeleteClick(e,data) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.dataToBeDeleted = data;
        this.setState({
            showDeleteDialog: true
        });
    }

<PivotItem linkText="My Scenarios" itemCount={this.state.scenarios.length} >
                                    <div className="tab-content">
                                        <div className="details-table">
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Last Modified</th>
                                                        <th>Owner</th>
                                                        <th className="actions">Actions</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.scenarios.map((scenariosItem, sIndex) => {
                                                            return (
                                                                <tr className="list-row" key={sIndex}>
                                                                    <td className="item-name">
                                                                        <div>
                                                                            <div className="item-icon"><i className="bod-industry-icon icon-Scenarios"></i></div>
                                                                            <div className="item-info">{scenariosItem.title}

                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td className="author">{moment(scenariosItem.utcDate).startOf('minutes').fromNow()}</td>
                                                                    <td className="activity">{scenariosItem.creator}</td>
                                                                    <td className="actions">
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Edit' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Edit"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                () => {
                                                                                    let url = '/c/scenarios/' + scenariosItem.ElementId;
                                                                                    window.open(url, '_self');
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        />
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'EdgeLogo' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Preview"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                () => {
                                                                                    let url = '/c/scenarios/' + scenariosItem.ElementId + "?preview=true";
                                                                                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        />
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Delete"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                (e) => this.onDeleteClick(e, scenariosItem)
                                                                            }
                                                                />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            );

                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        {
                                            this.state.scenarios.length > 0 ? <a className="pull-right" href="/c/search/?type=8&cat=1">View all records</a> : null
                                        }
                                    </div>
</PivotItem>
<PivotItem linkText="My Collections" itemCount={this.state.collections.length} >
                                    <div className="tab-content">
                                        <div className="details-table">
                                            <table>
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Last Modified</th>
                                                        <th>Owner</th>
                                                        <th className="actions">Actions</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    {
                                                        this.state.collections.map(function (collectionsItem, colIndex) {
                                                            const collectionIcon = collectionsItem.IndustryIcon ? collectionsItem.IndustryIcon : 'bod-industry-icon icon-Industry';
                                                            return (
                                                                <tr className="list-row" key={colIndex}>
                                                                    <td className="item-name">
                                                                        <div>
                                                                            <div className="item-icon"><i className={collectionIcon}></i></div>
                                                                            <div className="item-info">{collectionsItem.title}</div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td className="activity">{moment(collectionsItem.utcDate).startOf('minutes').fromNow()}</td>
                                                                    <td className="author">{collectionsItem.creator}</td>
                                                                    <td className="actions">
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Edit' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Edit"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                () => {
                                                                                    let url = '/c/collections/' + collectionsItem.ElementId;
                                                                                    window.open(url, '_self');
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        />
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'EdgeLogo' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Preview"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                () => {
                                                                                    let url = '/c/collections/' + collectionsItem.ElementId + "?preview=true";
                                                                                    window.open(url, '_blank');
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        />
                                                                        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: 'Delete' }}
                                                                            title=""
                                                                            ariaLabel="Delete"
                                                                            onClick={
                                                                                (e) => this.onDeleteClick(e, collectionsItem)
                                                                            }

                                                                />
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            );


                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        {
                                            this.state.collections.length > 0 ? <a className="pull-right" href="/c/search/?type=26&cat=1">View all records</a> : null
                                        }
                                    </div>
</PivotItem>
```

Comment: is onDeleteClick inside render function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your this.state.collections.map(function (collectionsItem, colIndex) {}) function as an arrow function.

Instead of defining it this way...

```
this.state.collections.map(function (collectionsItem, colIndex) {
})
```

Define it this way...

```
this.state.collections.map((collectionsItem, colIndex) => {
})
```

This will allow the function to inherit the arguments from its parent enclosing scope. In this case, it will inherit the arguments from the render function. Hence 'this' will reference the react component within your map function callback.

Also change your onDeleteClick definition to...

```
onDeleteClick = (e,data) => {
}
```

While working with React use arrow functions in most cases. However use normal functions while defining any of the react lifecycle functions such as componentDidMount, render, getDerivedStateFromProps etc.

```
componentDidMount() {
}
```

is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Its related to `lexical scope` issue.

Inside the **anonymous function** `function (collectionsItem, colIndex) {`

`this` refer to **global scope**,which don't have definition for `onDeleteClick`.

change this

```
 this.state.collections.map(function (collectionsItem, colIndex) {
```

to

```
 this.state.collections.map( (collectionsItem, colIndex)=> { //will bind class this
```

Comment: Thank u and i have a small doubt if use function how to write in that case i tried using bind but it didnot work

Comment: @BalajiV I have corrected answer. It should be like u used in your working snipper. `this.state.collections.map( (collectionsItem, colIndex)=> {` using arrow function

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with scoping.

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value.

This means that, the `this` inside `this.state.collections.map(function(collectionsItem, colIndex){` is a different `this`. You can use arrow functions, which will have the same `this` in order for it to work. Use `this.state.collections.map( (collectionsItem, colIndex) => {` for it to have the same `this`.

Read more on [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and `this`.